# I am getting error when I am retrieving data from firebase

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-realtime-database

I am posting this question because I haven't found any proper solution related to my problem.

I am trying to retrieve my user's data from Firebase but I am unable to do it. Please explain to me what I am doing wrong.

For this project, I am using Flask API. I also included all required indexes in my rules for the database. My error message accrues on line 106.

[Error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pnuA.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG5k0.png)

[Json for data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/576wH.png)

Comment: I would suggest you to log the complete error by replacing except: print("") with except Exception as e : print(e). This will give you the complete error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a default code required for getting data:

```py
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('Your url of the Real Time Database')
obj = firebase.get('/', None) #NOTE: '/' should be followed by the path in case you have child attributes
print(obj) #You will get a dictionary in return
```